# How is blood coming from the mouth filmed?

Tags: film-techniques

This is not like the other questions such as "how are gunshot and head gashes filmed". How are these scenes filmed where someone is talking and some action is going on such as in ***zombieland*** and the people (zombies) start spewing blood. They also just keep on spewing blood for a prolonged period of time on a single scene.

***How do they do this?***

Comment: I have linked to that question, because it kinda explains the blood used. They can easily fill this blood in their mouth and start spewing whenever required.

Comment: Yes, but that much blood is like they just took an enormous gulp out of a cup.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Generally they use fake blood capsules for this purpose. A capsule contains enough amount of red liquid which is released when gets broken.

Performers generally keep one or more, if necessary, in their mouth already and break it off when required.

In case of where the large amount of blood is being spewed, they can either already fill fake blood in their mouth or use a vessel with fake blood and a tube remarkably concealed through clothes or makeup around performer's body. Though this technique may require perfect camera angles and editing.

Here is the [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Blood-Capsules) how can one be made.

Here is also a [good explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/24468/27264) what kind of blood they use.

Answer (score 20):

There are blood capsules, like large pills made from gelatin or similar and filled with blood. The actor can keep these in their mouth and bite them open on cue to provide a trickle of blood. This method allows the actor to have the blood ready for some time but still be able to speak  so a scene can be filmed in a continuous shot.

For larger amounts of blood a simple solution is that they just have a mouthful of blood and spew it out on cue. Obviously you can only hold this amount of blood in your mouth for a limited time and so careful cutting and editing will be required to make the effect work.

For really large volumes of blood you would need a container concealed somewhere on the actor's body or otherwise out of shot with a tube running up to the actors mouth which can be concealed with clothing, makeup or prosthesis. Rather more care is needed in this case with camera angles and editing to make the effect work.

Of course in the case of zombies they will be wearing a lot of makeup and prosthetics anyway so there is more scope for hiding blood spray apparatus or even to use an entirely fake head for certain shots.

In the era of modern CGI a lot of blood and gore effects will be at least augmented if not done entirely with digital graphics in post production.

Comment: I assume when you say "blood" you mean "fake blood"? :)